# Which is correct: "full context" or "complete context"?

Tags: word-choice, differences, adjectives, articles

> "For the full context, see this."

vs.

> For the complete context, see this."

Are both identical in meaning?

Do I need the article "the"?

Please explain.

Comment: Isn't the context always full or complete? Why would not use "for context, see this"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though they are nearly identical in meaning, [this NGram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=full%20context,complete%20context&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows that "full context" is overwhelmingly preferred.  And yes, you do need the article "the" if you don't want to sound clipped.

Comment: I prefer them with "the", but they seem OK without.

Answer (score 1):

Both are absolutely correct. I prefer the second one, but I'm not sure why. Both sentences sound wrong without *the*. Sometimes we do use the noun *context* without the definite article, but since here it refers to a specific thing, namely the thing which the word *this* points to, it's appropriate.